# rabbitmq-peer-discovery-k8s fails. I still need to manually stop, join_cluster and start every node

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, kube-dns, kubernetes-statefulset, peer-discovery

Deployed the sample yaml files but doesn't work as expected. I still need to run a batch job on the cluster to manually stop, join_cluster and start for every pod. In addition, is there a way to configure vhosts, users and credentials using rabbitmq.conf file? Otherwise I have to do it in kerbernetes batch job after all the pods have booted up.

I have checked [Failing K8s rabbitmq-peer-discovery-k8s clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54563783/failing-k8s-rabbitmq-peer-discovery-k8s-clustering) and [k8s, RabbitMQ, and Peer Discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54311129/k8s-rabbitmq-and-peer-discovery). My cluster DNS works fine as it is able to resolve `kubernetes` to `kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: How did you deploy RabbitMQ cluster?

Comment: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-peer-discovery-k8s/issues/50

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you install RabbitMQ using the proper [Chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/rabbitmq-ha), even the prerequisite is having [Helm](https://helm.sh/) installed.